# Problema em salvar estados de acordo com as cidade em Angular 4

Tags: angular

Ao selecionar o estado ele está carregando perfeitamente as cidades de acordo com estado o problema é na hora de salvar ele troca as informações, preciso de ajuda para corrigir o algoritmo, acredito que seja coisa simples.

Eu acho que o problema está aqui!

```
buscarCidades() {
    console.log("Estado: " + this.uf);
      this.cidades = [];


     if(this.uf) {
        this.cidadesService.listarTodasCidades()
        .subscribe(cidades => {
          if (cidades.length > 0) {
            console.log("Qtd total de cidades: " + cidades.length);
          }
          for (let cidade of cidades) {
            if ( parseInt( cidade.codigoEstado) == parseInt(this.uf)) {
              console.log('valores da cidade codigo estado é ' + cidade.codigoEstado);
              console.log(cidade);
              this.cidades.push(cidade);

          }
        }

      });

    }
  }
```

Ele funciona da seguinte forma! Ao selecionar estado será armazenado o ID do estado na variavel **uf** ai depois ele vai comparar o ID do estado com o codigoEstado da entidade cidade, se for verdadeiro ai ele vai carregar somente as cidades que sejam realmente correspondente ao estado.

Porém ao submeter o formulário ele troca os registros porque o Algoritmo mostrado logo a cima somente consegue implementa as listagens das cidades de acordo com o estado mas para salvar ele troca os registros.

Preciso tentar corrigir isso, se alguém tiver dúvida estarei aqui para esclarecer para poder me ajudar.

Esse é meu componente:

```
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './../../core/error-handler.service';
import { ClientesService } from './../clientes.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CidadesService } from './../../cidades/cidades.service';
import { Estado, Cidade, Cliente } from './../../core/model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clientes-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './clientes-cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clientes-cadastro.component.css']
})
export class ClientesCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

//variaveis globais para a lista de estados e cidades
uf: string;

cidades: Cidade[];
estados: Estado[];

//variaveis globais para o campo CPF e CNPJ
  tipo: string;
  fisica = false;
  juridica = false;
  statusCampo = true;
  cidade = new Cidade();

cliente = new Cliente();


  statusMask() {
    if (this.tipo === null) {
      this.statusCampo = true;
    } else  if (this.tipo === 'FISICA') {
      this.fisica = true;
      this.juridica = false;
      this.statusCampo = false;
  }
  if (this.tipo === 'JURIDICA') {
    this.juridica = true;
    this.fisica = false;
    this.statusCampo = false;
  }
}


  constructor(
    private cidadesService: CidadesService,
    private clientesService: ClientesService,
    private erroHandler: ErrorHandlerService,
    private toasty: ToastyService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodosEstados()
    .subscribe(estados => this.estados = estados);
  }

  salvar(form: FormControl) {
    this.clientesService.adicionar(this.cliente)
      .then(() => {
        this.toasty.success('Cliente adicionado com sucesso!');

        form.reset();
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
      })
      .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
  }



  buscarCidades() {
    console.log("Estado: " + this.uf);
      this.cidades = [];


     if(this.uf) {
        this.cidadesService.listarTodasCidades()
        .subscribe(cidades => {
          if (cidades.length > 0) {
            console.log("Qtd total de cidades: " + cidades.length);
          }
          for (let cidade of cidades) {
            if ( parseInt( cidade.codigoEstado) == parseInt(this.uf)) {
              console.log('valores da cidade codigo estado é ' + cidade.codigoEstado);
              console.log(cidade);
              this.cidades.push(cidade);

          }
        }

      });

    }
  }




}
```

Essa é o trecho do codigo em HTML:

```
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-3 ui-md-4 ui-fluid">
        <label>Estado</label>
          <div>
              <select [(ngModel)]="cliente.endereco.cidade.estado.codigo" class="form-control"  name="estado" id="estado" [(ngModel)]="uf" (change)="buscarCidades()">
                      <option  *ngFor="let estado of estados" [value]="estado.codigo">{{estado.nome}}</option>
                </select>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-3 ui-md-4 ui-fluid">
        <label>Cidade</label>
        <div>
                <select [(ngModel)]="cliente.endereco.cidade.codigo" class="form-control"  name="cidade">
                              <option  *ngFor="let cidade of cidades" [value]="cidade.codigoEstado">{{cidade.nome}}</option>
                </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

O implementação está se comportando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esse é das cidades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje como ele está se comportando é assim, por exemplo, se olharem para a figurar dos estado no código 6 se refere a São Paulo, ai o usuário seleciona o São Paulo que é código 6, mas que na realidade ele está salvando no banco o Código 6 de cidade que é Goiâna no estado de Goias, é assim que hoje se encontra a incorreta implementação, preciso corrigir isso.

Comment: @Julio Henrique saberia como me ajudar?

Comment: vou compartilhar sua pergunta, pois não conheço muito de angular